# jquery undefined data return in ajax

Tags: javascript, grails

I'm using jQuery Mobile, and I need to remove `undefined` word that comes above the label. the `data` is json which return sucessfuly and build the html almost correctly. except the `undefined`
I have this dynamic code

HTML

```
<div class="ui-field-contain" id="selectNovoCorAnimal">
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function corAnimal(data){
    var html
    html += '<label for="corNovoAnimal" class="select">Cor</label>'
    html += '<select name="corNovoAnimal" id="corNovoAnimal" data-native-menu="false">'
        $.each(data, function (i, x) {
            html+='<option value='+ x.id + '>'+ x.descricao +'</option>';
        });
    html += '</select>'
    $('#selectNovoCorAnimal').html(html).enhanceWithin();
}
```

Which build like this:

```
undefined <<< need remove this
Cor
[Amarelo] << select
```

Why is giving me undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are not giving your `html` variable a initial value, so that value is `undefiend`. When you go to try to concat the rest of your html strings to it it converts `undefiend` to a string version and the rest of your html is added to that.

Simply set an initial value

```
var html = "";
```